# Why adding style through JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I am a beginner and I am learning JavaScript now. I am trying to make a javascript project. On this project, I am trying to add a style through javascript.
On my project, there is a button (anchor tag) named "Close". When it will click, the style `text-decoration: line-through` will be added to the description which id is `issue-{id}`.  But the style is not working. The style is not added when I am clicking on the close button.

**Look at the javascript code on line no 29 and 53**.

Here is my full code:

```js
document.getElementById('issueInputForm').addEventListener('submit', submitIssue);

let issueCounterEl = document.getElementById("issue-counter");

function submitIssue(e) {
    const getInputValue = id => document.getElementById(id).value;
    const description = getInputValue('issueDescription');
    const severity = getInputValue('issueSeverity');
    const assignedTo = getInputValue('issueAssignedTo');
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + '';
    const status = 'Open';
    const issue = { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status };
    let issues = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('issues')) {
        issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    }
    issues.push(issue);
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    document.getElementById('issueInputForm').reset();
    fetchIssues();
    e.preventDefault();
}

const closeIssue = id => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const currentIssue = issues.find(issue => issue.id == id);
    currentIssue.status = 'Closed';
    
    document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`).style.textDecoration = 'line-through'; // This line - line: 29. Id form line: 53

    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    fetchIssues();
}

const deleteIssue = id => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const remainingIssues = issues.filter(issue => issue.id != id)
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(remainingIssues));
    fetchIssues();
}

const fetchIssues = () => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const issuesList = document.getElementById('issuesList');
    issuesList.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
        const { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status } = issues[i];

        issuesList.innerHTML += `<div class="well">
                              <h6>Issue ID: ${id} </h6>
                              <p><span class="label label-info"> ${status} </span></p>
                              <h3 id="issue-${id}"> ${description} </h3> 
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> ${severity}</p>
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ${assignedTo}</p>
                              <a href="#" onclick="closeIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
                              <a href="#" onclick="deleteIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                              </div>`;
    }
    issueCounterEl.innerText = issues.length;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Issue Tracker: </title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body onload="fetchIssues()">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Issue Tracker: <span id="issue-counter"></span></h1>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
            <form id="issueInputForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueDescription">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueDescription" placeholder="Describe the issue ...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueSeverity">Severity</label>
                    <select id="issueSeverity" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueAssignedTo">Assigned To</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueAssignedTo" placeholder="Enter responsible ...">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="issuesList"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is no warning or error in the chrome dev tools.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You set the new style and THEN you call `fetchIssues()` which recreates the HTML with all new elements replacing the one that you just assigned the style to.  When you assign a style to a specific element, rather than a style that is applies via a style sheet, then that style only applies to that specific element.  When you replace the element with a new element, the previous manual style settings will not be on that new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all-right but has a small mistake. All you need to do is just put the line `` document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`).style.textDecoration = 'line-through'; `` after `fetchIssues();`.

Then it will look like this:

```
const closeIssue = id => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const currentIssue = issues.find(issue => issue.id == id);
    currentIssue.status = 'Closed';
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    fetchIssues();
    document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This is because you add the id on the wrong element, it should on `<h6>` and you put it on `<h3>`.
2. Comment your fetch method, because it will override the style you just applied.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/41kvwqye/

```
issuesList.innerHTML += `<div class="well">
                              <h6 id="issue-${id}">Issue ID: ${id} </h6>
                              <p><span class="label label-info"> ${status} </span></p>
                              <h3> ${description} </h3> 
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> ${severity}</p>
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ${assignedTo}</p>
                              <a href="#" onclick="closeIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
                              <a href="#" onclick="deleteIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                              </div>`;
```

Comment: Oh sorry. The id of `h3` is confusing you. I set it for `h3`, not for `h6`.  If I comment the fetch method the style is applying correctly but the innterText of `h6` is not changing form Open to Close.

Comment: Where is the text in? I can see the status changed from 'Open' to 'Closed' after clicking the close button. Please check the previous fiddle carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the strike through effect in UI because you are always display the information from the local storage setup. **You are not updating the strike through style effect on your local storage information.** So before fetching your information update your local storage information for the specific id with the strike through style effect like below.

Instead of

```
document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`).style.textDecoration = 'line-through'; // This line - line: 29. Id form line: 53
```

Use below

```
issues.find(issue => issue.id == id).style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
```

The above line will update the local storage value and you can see the effect in UI.

```js
document.getElementById('issueInputForm').addEventListener('submit', submitIssue);

let issueCounterEl = document.getElementById("issue-counter");

function submitIssue(e) {
    const getInputValue = id => document.getElementById(id).value;
    const description = getInputValue('issueDescription');
    const severity = getInputValue('issueSeverity');
    const assignedTo = getInputValue('issueAssignedTo');
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + '';
    const status = 'Open';
    const issue = { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status };
    let issues = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('issues')) {
        issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    }
    issues.push(issue);
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    document.getElementById('issueInputForm').reset();
    fetchIssues();
    e.preventDefault();
}

const closeIssue = id => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const currentIssue = issues.find(issue => issue.id == id);
    currentIssue.status = 'Closed';    
    issues.find(issue => issue.id == id).style.textDecoration = 'line-through';

    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    fetchIssues();
}

const deleteIssue = id => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const remainingIssues = issues.filter(issue => issue.id != id)
    localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(remainingIssues));
   fetchIssues();
}

const fetchIssues = () => {
    const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    const issuesList = document.getElementById('issuesList');
    issuesList.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
        const { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status } = issues[i];

        issuesList.innerHTML += `<div class="well">
                              <h6>Issue ID: ${id} </h6>
                              <p><span class="label label-info"> ${status} </span></p>
                              <h3 id="issue-${id}"> ${description} </h3> 
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> ${severity}</p>
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ${assignedTo}</p>
                              <a href="#" onclick="closeIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
                              <a href="#" onclick="deleteIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                              </div>`;
    }
    issueCounterEl.innerText = issues.length;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Issue Tracker: </title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body onload="fetchIssues()">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Issue Tracker: <span id="issue-counter"></span></h1>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
            <form id="issueInputForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueDescription">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueDescription" placeholder="Describe the issue ...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueSeverity">Severity</label>
                    <select id="issueSeverity" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="issueAssignedTo">Assigned To</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueAssignedTo" placeholder="Enter responsible ...">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="issuesList"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript runs before your done is rendered, so you need to wait for it to finished and you do that with

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
/// add code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tip: (not going to solve your problem)
Set another variable as the element:

```
issueid = document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`)
```

Then, do the following:

```
issueid.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
```

(I know this should be in the comments but I don't have enough rep.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById(`issue-${id}`).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```